# how can generate a image URL from image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am working on a face recognition API that accept only image URL .

I want to generate a image URL from image of my local computer in python .Any solution to generate the image URL in python ? so I can pass the image URL in to API (that only take image URL).

Here is my code :

```
import requests

# put your keys in the header
headers = {
    "app_id": "4353454",
    "app_key": "5474565rfedgry564353tgtr"
}

#here I want to convert the image to image URL so I can easily pass it as a 
argument into API

payload = '{"image":"image_URL"}'

url = "url_of_API"

r = requests.post(url, data= payload, headers=headers)
print(r.content)
```

Any solution will highly appreciated .

Comment: can you please elaborate the question? What do you want to achieve? Do you want to get the path of an image? to insert later into face recognition API?

Comment: Yes I want to get a image URL path , so I can pass it into API because the API only gets the image URL

Comment: You need to state what framework you are working with? Django and Flask both support file uploads in a different way. You will have to also state the underlying data model of how you store your images.

Comment: I donot find any solution to generate image URL from my local PC image in python .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to send the URLs to external APIs, your images need to be hosted somewhere. If your machine is communicating locally, you can simply run

```
python -m http.server
```

in your images folder. Then you will get URLs like

**127.0.0.1:8000/myImg.png**

To access this on another machine in same network, the url would be:

**IPv4ofMachine:8000/myImg.png**

You can get IPv4 of the host machine by running "ipconfig" in your CMD.

Now, if you want to communicate with external host/ API Services which is asking for image URL, you have to host those image somewhere. I would suggest **AWS S3** buckets. It is really easy and free to use. By uploading it there, you will get a clear URL of your images which further can be used on web.

Comment: this answer has some misguides. ipconfig/ifconfig does not give you public ip adresses. even if you manage to get the public ip, you also need to open port for external connections etc. 
but what OP actually tries to get is, exatly that one. otherwise the API endpoint would not recognize which image should it process

Answer (score 1):

Run the command `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` (python2) or `python -m http.server` (python3) to turn a folder to a web application. The folder is where you leave your images. You could retrieve any images under this folder as any URL based resources.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this generate the image URL of local host that is accessible only my machine , but I want to pass this URL as the argument of API & API give the response "invalid url was sent"

Answer (score 1):

Navigate the folder where images are located. Then start a simple file server with `SimpleHTTPServer` (2), or `http.server` (3).

```
$ cd images_directory
$ python3 -m http.server  // python2 -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

this will let you, access images via web with urls like, 'http://localhost:8000/image.jpg'

**EDIT:**

```
from mimetypes import MimeTypes
mime = MimeTypes()


def make_url(mime_type, bin_data):
    return 'data:'+f_mime+';base64, '+bin_data

your_files_mimetype = mime.guess_type(path_to_your_file)[0] #3 returns a tuple

with open(path_to_your_file, 'rb') as f:
      data = f.read().encode('base64')
      url = make_url(your_files_mimetype, data)
```

then use that url.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this generate the image URL of local host that is accessible only my machine , but I want to pass this URL as the argument of API & API give the response "invalid url was sent"

Comment: i thought your api endpoint was also on your machine. let me update asnwer

Comment: updated answer, have a look up if that works for you

Answer (score 0):

There are bots in telegram which can convert image to url you will need to use telegram  api to upload image to bot and it will reply with url